# Correct phone number format on Amplify Auth / Cognito?

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm trying to signup to a site I created with AWS Amplify. I added Auth and clicked to allow signing in with both email and phone number. However, when I try creating an account, I get an error saying the phone number format is incorrect. So far I've tried:

- +17184625510
- 7184625510
- 718-462-5510
- etc

but I consistently get the following error. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to AWS Cognito, `The phone number must be in E.164 format`. eg. "+12065550100".

Comment: Right, e164 is the first thing I tried and it fails validation. I suspect the issue may be the codegen'd UI component handling validation.

Comment: Could you please add signup function code in question... to check issue in more details

Comment: AWS Amplify Auth uses the Cognito Hosted UI, so there's no code to show as I didn't have to write any. This seems like a bug in the autogenerated code so for now I'm just going to force folks to only use email for account creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in the Amplify UI which you can read more about in the corresponding [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui/issues/1043) where there is also a proposed workaround for the problem that you can try until the problem is fixed.

The problem is that the +1 that is entered as a default for the country code is `undefined` in the code. Everything currently works if you switch from +1 to another country code (or to another country code and back to +1 again). If your users are not in the +1 region they probably won't notice, otherwise take a look at the workaround.